# Searching for records in list view when more than 2000 rows

Tags: soql, custom-object, governorlimits, search

I have a custom object that has more than 2000 records. I have a custom field, `id__c`, that is a number that is searchable. The records I have in there have `id__c`'s ranging from 1 to 3000.

I am running into an issue with the default List that is created on the objects tab when you create a custom Object.

If I have the object's list sorted by `id__c` ascending, and search for `2000` the correct record appears, but if I search for `2001` it does not appear and I get `No Results`.

If I have the object's list sorted by `id__c` descending, and search for `2001` the correct record appears, but if I search for `999` is doesn't appear.

I can only assume that this has something to do with SF's `2000` limit restriction on OFFSET in SOQL and that they pre-load the first 2000 records and search through those results rather than actually search for all users?

EDIT:

As requested, here are some pictures of what I mean. For these pictures, I have sorted the list by 'Student Name'.

In this picture, you will see that when sorted by Name, the 2000th record is `AGFEYTPtest854`:

[image: 2000th record]

In the next picture, I have reloaded the page and sorted by Name, and searched for `AGFEYTPtest854` and you will see there is a search result:

[image: AGFEYTPtest854]

In this third picture, I searched for `AGFEYTPtest855` and there is no results:

[image: AGFEYTPtest855]

And just to confirm that this record does in fact exist, here is my search result when I have the list sorted by a different field:

[image: AGFEYTPtest855 - 2]

So as you can see, I don't do the SOQL query. Why does this search bar only search for the first 2000 records depending on the current sort? Shouldn't a search on a particular list, you know, search the whole list?

Comment: Please post your actual SOQL query.

Comment: It’s not an SOQL query, it’s the default List Salesforce creates for a new object, you know, like in an Objects Tab.  I just said I can only assume the problem relates to SOQL restrictions.

Comment: @BlondeSwan I think I follow you but a couple of screenshots might help show the behavior you're talking about.

Comment: @DavidReed I've added the screenshots for your viewing pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

max 2000 record per 1 query on listview is a standard limitation.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_listviewresults.htm?search_text=list%20view

Lightning does not come out of the box with pagination on list views.
However, in classic, with the enhanced UI, you can get pagination on list views. - Because it's implementing offseting on listview queries.
[image]

However, you can accomodate custom page on object tab which will include a lightning component work together with offsets and listviews somehow.
For example, the dreamhouse example app has a paginator component written in LWC.
https://github.com/dreamhouseapp/dreamhouse-lwc/tree/c7a6f90f55080524123fef25a293ded773b36b23/force-app/main/default/lwc/paginator

By checking it's references you can get a picture how you can accomplish it, if you want to.

Check out this discussions within this topic:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iS6cQAE
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003bruQAA

Comment: What a pointless search bar...

Comment: If folks could kindly upvote https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWgTUAV/lightning-list-view-pagination. 

In the meantime, an interesting hack could be to auto-create list views via the meta-data API depending on the # of records. So for example, if a list view would normally be 4,900 rows then create 6 list views of 2k rows each. Very hacky but fun (depending on who you ask).